# D3.js v4: Access current DOM element in ES6 arrow function event listener

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In D3.js v4, when registering an event listener through a traditional callback function, `this` references the current DOM element:

```
d3.select("div").on('mouseenter', function() {
  d3.select(this).text("Yay");
});
```

ES6 offers arrow functions, which IMHO make D3.js code a lot more readable because they are very concise. However, traditional callbacks cannot blindly be replaced with arrow functions:

```
d3.select("div").on('mouseenter', () => {
  d3.select(this); // undefined
});
```

The article "[On D3 and Arrow Functions](https://medium.com/@yonester/on-d3-and-arrow-functions-b6559c1cebb8#.34m7omc3j)" gives a very good explanation of why `this` is not bound as expected. The article suggests using traditional callbacks for code that needs access to the current DOM element.

Is it possible to access the current DOM element **from an arrow function**?

Answer (score 10):

There is an **idiomatic** way of doing this in D3: just use the less famous *third argument*:

```
selection.on("mouseenter", (d, i, nodes) => {
    d3.select(nodes[i]);
});
```

And that's the same of:

```
selection.on("mouseenter", function() {
    d3.select(this);
});
```

I wrote an example here: [d3 v4 retrieve drag DOM target from drag callback when `this` is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262172/d3-v4-retrieve-drag-dom-target-from-drag-callback-when-this-is-not-available/45262284#45262284)

Here is a demo:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", (d, i, p) => {
        d3.select(p[i]).attr("fill", "maroon")
    })
    .on("mouseout", (d, i, p) => {
        d3.select(p[i]).attr("fill", "seagreen")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
</svg>
```

Actually, if you look at the end of the article you linked, he gives the same solution.

Your [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41532636/5768908), `d3.event.target`, despite working for event listeners, **does not work** in several situations. For instance:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle").each(()=>d3.select(d3.event.target).attr("fill", "red"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
</svg>
```

But the same code works using the third argument:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle").each((d,i,p)=>d3.select(p[i]).attr("fill", "red"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
 <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="20" fill="seagreen"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this solution. While it may be the "idiomatic" way, IMHO `d3.select(d3.event.target)` is more readable than `d3.select(nodes[i])`. But it's good to have multiple approaches so people can choose!

Comment: I don't know if `d3.event.target` is "more readable", that's opinion-based. But I know this: it's *not* the same of `this` and, more important, it only works in specific situations (I'm aware of "event listeners" in your question's title). See my edit.

Comment: Yes, I agree, my comment about readability is specific to the event listener example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use an ES6 arrow function and access the current DOM element via `d3.event.target`:

```
d3.select("div").on('mouseenter', () => {
  d3.select(d3.event.target).text("Yay, this works!");
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `d`, the `event` parameter?

Comment: Nope, I really meant [d3.event](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#event). `d` is not actually used, I will remove it for clarity...

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what's the point?  It is certainly not more readable than normal function. The purpose of arrow function is to provide lexical `this`. Which is not the case for older libraries that weren't written with this concern in mind.

Comment: They are certainly more readable for simple things like `.attr("x", d => xScale(d))`. Personally, I'd rather use them consistently, i.e. not mix with traditional syntax. But that's just my two cents (coming from Scala / FP).

Comment: Yes, one-liners with implied `return` are strong part of arrows - but only where they are necessary. Otherwise it is an antipattern. Unintentional return may screw up the things (very common among coffeescript devs, where ES6 arrows were borrowed from). And it supposes the wrong signature (TS or Flow may not be happy with such callback). I like arrows a lot and stick to them wherever it is prctical, but here an anonymous `function` function looks very consistent. It designates that a callback uses non-lexical `this` (would be nice to have Coffee `->` thin arrows also in JS, but there are none)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how `d3.event.target` works, but it looks like it is assigned synchronously on each event. This means that `.on(..., () => {
  setTimeout(() => { ...d3.event.target... }, 100) })` may refer to wrong target. That's a matter of taste to some degree, but an arrow looks inappropriate to me in cases like that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed clarifications. As mentioned, I have a Java/Scala background, so a lot to learn in the JS world. If an arrow function really leads to wrong behavior, then obviously it is the wrong choice...

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Even familiar things can have different semantics in different languages. Btw, when there are more than 1 respondent in SO comments, a user should be addressed directly with @netzwerg. I've seen your last comment by pure chance.