# D3 - get x position on mouseover

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/iOGJUosvruW9KV1FF9lp?p=preview

On mouseover of the bars I want to show a tooltip

At the moment it move with the mouse but I want it to be a set position above the bars I'm over.

How do I get the x and y position of the bar I'm over

I have tried, but I get errors.

```
console.log(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As [explained in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not have its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Arrow functions are introduced to be [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and that's the reason why they don't have this kind of context variables.

Just convert the arrow function to a regular one. I forked your plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3Y4T0JZ42eH2wb42tpsg?p=preview

```
d3.selectAll('.bar').on("mouseover", function(){
   console.log(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
   d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style("display", null)
})
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also replace this with the global `d3.event.target` and keep the function as an arrow function.

```
d3.selectAll('.bar').on("mouseover", () => {
  console.log(d3.mouse(d3.event.target)[0]);
  d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style("display", null)
})
```

**UPDATE II:**

[Gerardo Furtado proposed to use the third argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532635/d3-js-v4-access-current-dom-element-in-es6-arrow-function-event-listener/42667743#42667743) of the callback to get the html element. Also a good solution, as `d3.event` can be problematic in certain situations.

```
d3.selectAll('.bar').on("mouseover", (datum,index,elements) => {
  console.log(d3.mouse(elements[index])[0]);
  d3.select('.chart-tooltip').style("display", null)
})
```

Comment: +1, but `d3.event.target` is not a good alternative for arrow functions, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667743/5768908. Just use the third and second arguments.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado updated!